# Create a group of which the users should have no permissions anywhere in this sitecollection

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups

I want to create a group of users in a site collection. The group should only be for user with restricted permissions. The users in this group should literally be not able to view any page in a site collection. Lets call it a "blind user".

What I done yet: I have created the group and dont apply any permissions in the creation window. I have added a user to this group. I tried to view a few pages in the SiteCollection but he always the permission to view this page.

Is it possible to create a group of user like that and how whould it be done?

Comment: This might not work if a user is also added in another group with higher permissions

Comment: @KushalBhabra there are some groups in which "Everyone" is in the group and has permissions to view all the pages. Is it possible to force a user to only use one group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's permitted group with "Everyone" in use you cannot deny access from specified users.

There's Deny option on Web Application level but not on site collection or lower level.